# Replace click-once application with msix counterpart

Tags: .net, .net-core, upgrade, clickonce, msix

I'am I trying to migrate an old legacy click-once application, written in. Net and winforms. I (think) want to lift it to msix and.net core. But there is something in click-once that seems impossible to do with msix. 
The list of things that msix would need to do.

1. Install from web page(check)
2. Update or forced update from "web page"(check)
3. Possible to uninstall from client computer (check)
4. Start app from web page with arguments included (no?)

And it's the last part that give me the problem. The legacy app starts with a click on a link that contains information on which circumstances it has been started. Sure this can be entered when starting program, but it seems that going from something automatic to manual, is not a thing that will be appreciated.
Is this possible to autostart app with arguments?
What should look at?

Comment: A note that ClickOnce is now supported on .NET 3.1 and .NET 5:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder

Comment: Yes I saw that... How nice :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MSIX shortcut arguments](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-shortcut.html) is a *hot* topic for the MSIX team. Multiple users have requested improvements, starting with support for command-line arguments. They promised to bring some native support in future releases.

Until then, you can partially address your scenario with workarounds, like the one we implemented in Advanced Installer (i.e. use a stub to pass the argument to your shortcut target). Many similar tools should provide this support by now, not just Advanced Installer.

However, this gives you a fixed command line for your shortcut. You cannot customize it from a download link on your website (*if I understand correctly your requirement*).

Here are more related topics on migrating from ClickOnce to MSIX:

- [Can a MSIX package use an external file for user settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147009/can-a-msix-package-use-an-external-file-for-user-settings/60167186#60167186)
- [How to create an MSIX package for WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759398/how-to-create-an-msix-package-for-winforms-app/59765849#59765849)

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Thanks for your information.Will still wait the continued development of msix that hopefully will solve this problem